# Django-Celery in production?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

So I've been trying to figure out how to make scheduled tasks, I've found Celery and been able to to make simple scheduled tasks. To do this I need to open up a command line and run `celery -A proj beat` for the tasks to happen. This works fine in a development environment, but when putting this into production that will be an issue.

So how can I get celery to work without the command line use? When my production server is online, how can I make sure my scheduler goes up with it? Can Celery do this or do I need to go down another method?

Comment: What issue are you exactly expecting to occur in production?

Comment: That I won't be able to run celery without having my computer on the whole time even through the server is on another computer.

Comment: You can always daemonize it. Check this out, http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html

Comment: Is that for possible for Windows 64-bit?

Comment: The link I provided has scripts only for linux systems. Check this link http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/07/04/django-on-windows-run-celery-as-a-windows-service/ (Its outdated but should give you some idea)

Answer (score 4):

We use Celery in our production environment, which happens to be on Heroku. We are in the process of moving to AWS. In both environments, Celery hums along nicely.

It would be helpful to understand what your production environment will look like. I'm slightly confused as to why you would be worried about turning off your computer, as using Django implies that you are running serving up a website... Are you serving your website from your laptop??

Anyway, assuming that you are going to run your production server from a cloud platform, all you have to do is send whatever command lines you need to run Django AND the command lines for Celery (as you have already noted in your question).

In terms of configuration, you say that you have 'scheduled' tasks, so that implies you have set up a beat schedule in your config.py file. If not, it should look something like this (assumes you have a module called tasks.py which holds your celery task definitions:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

beat_schedule = {
    'task1': {
        'task': 'tasks.task_one',
        'schedule': 3600
    },
    'task2': {
        'task': 'tibController.tasks.update_old_retail',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=0, day_of_week='mon-fri'
    }
}
```

Then in your tasks.py just call the config file you just do this:

```
from celery import Celery
import config

app = Celery('tasks')
app.config_from_object(config)
```

You can find more on crontab in the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). You can also checkout this [repo](https://github.com/greenberge/celery_example) for a simple Celery example.

In summary:

1. Create a config file that identifies which tasks to run when
2. Load the config file into your Celery app
3. Get a cloud platform to run your code on.
4. Run celery exactly like you have already identified

Hope that helps.

Comment: so basically setting this up wouldn't require typing `celery -A proj beat` on terminal ?

Comment: Yes, you would still want to run the beat command so that Celery knows to start it. Here is how I start my celery: `celery -A task_module.tasks worker --loglevel=info --beat` .