# Django+Celery+RabbitMQ, Does Celery need separate server in production?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have recently learned to integrate Celery + RabbitMQ in local machine, all three of them were running in separate servers.

During production, should I run celery & RabbitMQ in separate server ?

I have searched for Celery hosting options but couldn't find useful links.

*I usually use Pythonanywhere to host my Django app*

*I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105723/10515390 answer useful but did't get a clarification*

Comment: *"...all three of them were running in separate servers."* I don't understand what do you mean my ***servers*** here?

Comment: I mean terminal,

Comment: Running parts of your application on different servers, or containers if you can, means that scaling up parts of your application becomes easier in the long run. If the app is not under any significant load it's probably fine just to put it on one server and solve the problem when you need to

Comment: also, failure of one server will not affect the other ones, *to an extent*